# Multiple nicks for a bot

Tags: slack-api, slack

Is there a way a bot can show up as multiple users connected at the same time in a channel?

Use case: `slack <-> irc` proxy with all the users in the IRC channel appearing in the slack channel.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that is possible, but you can use IRC (and XMPP) as client to connect to your Slack team in case that is what you are trying to do.

All you need to do is enable this option under Permissions / Gateways.

Check [here](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/201727913-Connect-to-Slack-over-IRC-and-XMPP) for the official help page on the topic.

Comment: No, that is not what i'm trying to achieve. i want to create a real proxy that would make N:M communication possible.

Comment: Gotcha. As I said - don't think that is possible. You can only have 1 bot user per Slack app which has to be installed with Oauth.